# .net core 2.2 for linux red hat

Tags: c#, .net-core, redhat

I am using .net core 2.2 and I am new to Linux Red Hat and I have a console that I need to run on Red Hat server that is only ssh (no GUI), I have downloaded .net core 2.2 for Red Hat from here

> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/rhel/runtime-2.2.3

but I found that i need to register a .net core subscription on the server and I can't find the .net core subscription anywhere

references: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/2.2/html/getting_started_guide/gs_install_dotnet

https://developers.redhat.com/products/dotnet/hello-world#fndtn-windows

Comment: "I found that i need to register a .net core subscription on the server", what? .NET Core is Open-Source, from where exactly did you take that extremely wrong idea? If you mean the Red Hat Subscription, that's completely unrelated to .NET Core and that's a problem you have to solve by buying the Red Hat subscription

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i have set the references links in my question

Comment: You did not answer my question. The only subscription I see in your links is a Red Had subscription.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i said i was new to red hat so you could have just helped me instead of all this mean words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a mixup of a few things.

If you are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)*, you have two ways to get .NET Core 2.2:

1. Install from RHEL repositories.

   This installs `dotnet` packages that behave like other programming languages (such as `python` available on RHEL). The system tools like `yum` will let you install, upgrade and remove your packages. Red Hat - as the vendor - will be responsible for keeping your package up to date.

   This requires - like any other RHEL package - for you to have access to the RHEL package repositories. These repositories are only available once you have registered and subscribed your system. You also get the benefits of Red Hat's support system, if you need it.

   Both Red Hat's documentation and The "package manager" documentation on Microsoft's website suggest you do this.
2. Install from Microsoft's website.

   You can ignore the RHEL packages and just download and install from Microsoft's website. You should follow the steps on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.300-linux-x64-binaries. You can install to any location. But you are now responsible for keeping the binary up-to-date. And Red Hat won't directly support you if something is broken (but Microsoft should).

So, you should figure out what you want to install: either the packages from Red Hat or the tarball from Microsoft's website. And then follow all the steps for that particular process.

* Small gotcha: .NET Core 2.2 is available in RHEL package repository only on RHEL 7, not on RHEL 8.